# Name of a word play

Tags: rhetorical-devices

Russell one wrote:

> Between two quantities there is a conception of difference, but no difference of conception.

Is there a name for this kind of word play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **chiasmus** *noun*, a reversal in the order of words in two otherwise parallel phrases

[Definition of chiasmus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chiasmus)

[Wikipedia entry for chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of chiasmus, but more specifically, it's Antimetabole because the *exact same* words are used as opposed to just reversing the structure, which is chiasmus. Another famous example is MacBeth's "Fair is foul and foul is fair", if that helps.